How can i install the intel hda sound driver?
Ive already tried reinstalling alsa and also the modprobe command and nothing worked.
The only thing that shows up when i try to turn up my volume/test audio is "Dummy Output".
Im using a HP Chromebook x360 (Yes. A chromebook.)
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Im sing Pipewire
(reinstalling alsa did nothing as i dont have access to a keyboard thar has fn keys at the moment)

Also when i plug in headphones instead of going through the headphones it goes to the normal speakers.
